# LINQ XML Getting combobox value from another form c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, label

I want to display xml information in a label between two forms but I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I've been searching for hours but no solution yet.

**cbFrom** and **cbTo** are my two textboxs that i need to send their values from one **FORM1** to another **FORM2**

```
public partial class FORM1 : Form
{
    public string combofrom
    {
        get { return cbFrom.Text; }
        set { cbFrom.Text = value; }
    }

    public string comboto
    {
        get { return cbTo.Text; }
        set { cbTo.Text = value; }
    }
  }
```

FORM2

```
   public partial class FORM2 : Form
{
 public FORM2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private FORM1 = new FORM1();

     public FORM1(FORM2 form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("schedulemanager.xml");

        var n = from ep in xmlDoc.Descendants("Aircraft")
                 where ep.Attribute("mdy").Equals(form.combofrom.ToString())
                 select ep;

        label8.Text = n.FirstOrDefault().ToString();// ****Object reference     
                                      //not set to an instance of an object

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 
Finally I find a solution.

FORM1

```
     public void FORM1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    FORM2 f2 = new FORM2(this);
    }
    /**You don't need any getter or setter
```

FORM2

```
     private FORM2 f2;
     public frmScheduleResult( frmReservation f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f2 = f;

    }

     var name = xmlDoc.Descendants("Aircraft")

        .Where(n => n.Attribute("Source").Value == f1.cbFrom.Text)
        .Select(n => (string)n) 
        .FirstOrDefault();      
         label7.Text = name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,I hope it will helpful for you:

```
String name = xmlDoc.Descendants("Aircraft")
              .Elements("Name")
              .Where(n => (string)n.Attribute("mdy") == form.combofrom.ToString())
              .Select(n => (string)n) // get element's value
              .FirstOrDefault();      // select only first value, if any

label8.Text = name.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you, this code seems to work but label is dissapearing instead of showing the value! Very bizzare. What else can I do??

Comment: I tried name.toString() and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object showed up" :/ I really can't understand what is wrong. Code logic is correct.

Comment: @Nikos Super :)))

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(form.combofrom!=null)
{

  var n = (from ep in xmlDoc.Descendants("Aircraft")
                     where ep.Attribute("mdy").Equals(form.combofrom.ToString())
                     select ep).FirstOrDefault();

    if(n!=null)
    {
     label8.Text = n.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: still got error message "Object reference     
                                      "not set to an instance of an object"...but why??

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the updated code didn't change anything. I'm now trying another way to pass values between forms. I think form.combofrom is always null

Comment: Thank you all for your replies I find it. Cheers!